# let function $f : [a,b] \to [a,b]$ be a differentiable contraction, show $\sup |f'(x)| < 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $x,y \in X$ with $x < y$.
$f$ is differentiable hence there is an $x' \in (x,y)$ such that

$$|f(x) − f(y)| = |f′(x') \cdot (y − x)| = |f'(x')| \cdot |(y − x)| \leq r \cdot |x − y|.$$

Comment: For a specific example you could consider $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and $f(x) = \frac 12 x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

The title statement is false.  For example, $f\colon [-1,1]\to[-1,1], x\mapsto\arctan(x)$ is a contraction (exercise) and $f'(0)=1$.

---

**Addendum**: "contraction" means a nonexpansive self-map, and a "contraction mapping", or "strict contraction", is a contraction where distance is decreased by a factor ("contraction constant") $k\in[0,1)$.

Comment: Why do you think $\arctan x$ is a contraction?

Comment: @zhw. Why do you think not?  It is exercise for the OP.

Comment: See my answer.$\,\,$

Comment: @zhw. You and I are using two different definitions of contractions.  I never use "contraction" on its own, always use "contraction mapping" or similar, because of this ambiguity.

Answer (score -1):

By definition of a contraction, there exists $k\in [0,1)$ such that $|f(y)-f(x)|\le k|y-x|$ for all $x,y\in [a,b].$ Let $x\in [a,b].$ Suppose $y\in [a,b], y\ne x.$ Then

$$\left|\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\right | \le k.$$

As $y\to x,$ the left side $\to |f'(x)|.$ Therefore $|f'(x)|\le k.$ It follows that $\sup_{[a,b]}|f'| \le k <1,$ which is the desired conclusion.

Comment: @user10354138 So you think there is $k\in [0,1)$ such that $|\arctan x -0|\le k|x|?$